# A problem about restriction of measure relating to $\sigma$-finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

R is a set-ring, and S(R) is the $\sigma$-ring generated by R. m is a $\sigma$-finite measure on S(R), if m restricted to R is still a measure on R, is it $\sigma$-finite? If not, can a counter example be given?